Help with Unexpected token 'Last_Court_Date_DS__c'. at line 13 column 23
I'm super new at Apex coding and most of this works fine. I want to compare two date fields as part of the filter for the list. I've tried with a static date rather than a formula date field and it works but I need to use the formula field for it to do what I need it to do.
Thanks in advance!
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getDirectServicesByCase')
global with sharing class GetDirectServicesByCase {

@HttpPost
global static List<Results> getDirectServicesByCase(String caseId) {

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dsTTL = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dsTOTAL = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dsTTLDUR = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Date__c > Last_Court_Date_DS__c];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dsTOTALDUR = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Date__c > Last_Court_Date_DS__c];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dstIND = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Client_Session__c!=null
AND ExpECM__Client_Attendance__c='Attended'];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dstGRP = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Group_Class_Assignment__c!=null
AND ExpECM__Client_Attendance__c='Attended'];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dstINDDUR = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Client_Session__c!=null
AND ExpECM__Client_Attendance__c='Attended'
AND ExpECM__Date__c > Last_Court_Date_DS__c];

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> dstGRPDUR = [SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c 
WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId
AND ExpECM__Group_Class_Assignment__c!=null
AND ExpECM__Client_Attendance__c='Attended'
AND ExpECM__Date__c > Last_Court_Date_DS__c];

Results res = new Results();

res.total = String.valueOf(dsTTL.size());
res.ttl = String.valueOf(dstGRP.size()+dstIND.size()) + ' out of ' + String.valueOf(dsTOTAL.size());
res.individual = String.valueOf(dstIND.size()) + ' out of ' + res.total;
res.ggroup = String.valueOf(dstGRP.size()) + ' out of ' + res.total;

res.totalduring = String.valueOf(dsTTLDUR.size());
res.ttlduring = String.valueOf(dstGRPDUR.size()+dstINDDUR.size()) + ' out of ' + String.valueOf(dsTOTALDUR.size());
res.individualduring = String.valueOf(dstINDDUR.size()) + ' out of ' + res.totalduring;
res.groupduring = String.valueOf(dstGRPDUR.size()) + ' out of ' + res.totalduring;

return new List<Results>{res};
}

global class Results{
String individual;
String ggroup;
String ttl;
String total;
String individualduring;
String groupduring;
String ttlduring;
String totalduring;
}
}


In SOQL, you cannot place a field on the right side of a comparison.  Furthermore, you can't use Apex variables in your use case because the value could be different for each record.
The easiest workaround is to create a Boolean formula field in your object that compares the two date fields.  Then you can build a SOQL query like this:
SELECT Id FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c WHERE MyFormula__c = TRUE

But even better, you can do some major optimization in your code.  Right now you are executing multiple queries with very similar criteria, so you're filling up your governor limits by querying the same record multiple times.
Since all of your queries require ExpECM__Case_Record__c=: caseId, you should do just a single SOQL query with just this single criterion, and include the formula field in the SOQL field list.  Then you can loop through the records and add each record to the specific list that you need.  Of course you would use the MyFormula__c field in if() statements as needed.
So your code structure would be something this:
List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> subList1 = new List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c>();
List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> subList2 = new List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c>();
more sublists here

List<ExpECM__Direct_Service__c> theBigList = [SELECT a bunch of fields FROM ExpECM__Direct_Service__c WHERE ExpECM__Case_Record__c = :caseId];

for (ExpECM__Direct_Service__c ds : theBigList) {
    if (ds.Field1__c == something && ds.MyFormula__c == TRUE) {
        sublist1.add(ds);
    } else if (ds.Field2__c == something) {
        sublist2.add(ds);
    } else more if statements and list.adds
}

